# Avoiding including glib twice

Tags: c, header-files

I've a main.c file that has three functions (beside main). All three make use of GString type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

const char * SOME_CONST = "const123";

void doo() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and SOME_CONST
}

void bar() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and doo function
    doo();
}

void foo() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and curl routines
    bar();
}

void main() {
    foo()
}
```

I was planning on split this code as:

- main.c
- constants.h
- utils.h
- http_func.h

for `main.c` file I would presume it would become:

```
// main.c
#include "http_func.h"

void main() {
    foo()
}
```

for `constants.h` would be:

```
// constants.h
#ifndef CONSTANT_FILE
#define CONSTANT_FILE
const char * SOME_CONST = "const123";
#endif
```

for `utils.h` would be:

```
// utils.h
#ifndef UTILS_FILE
#define UTILS_FILE
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include "constants.h"

void doo() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and SOME_CONST
}

#endif
```

for `http_func.h` would be:

```
// http_func.h
#ifndef HTTPFUNC_FILE
#define HTTPFUNC_FILE
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "utils.h"

void bar() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and doo function
    doo();
}

void foo() {
    // this function makes use of:
    // GString and curl routines
    bar();
}

#endif
```

My question here is: Would glib be imported twice with those changes? If yes, what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: This is what those `#ifndef/#define/#endif` guards are for in headers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Don't put function definitions in header files. You can put declarations (prototypes) for them in header files.

Comment: basically `<glib-2.0/glib.h>` is just plain old ASCII text, is not a library. The text is parsed twice (by the compiler proper), the library is included once (by the linker).

Comment: It is up to `glib` authors to deal with that. They probably included the `#ifndef/#define/#endif` guards, indeed. Or they didn't because it may not matter. `glib.h` is just the header, not the code. It is not like including it twice increase the size of the program or anything. If it contains only function declarations for example, it is not a problem if they are read twice. It is not, strictly speaking code (in the sense that it doesn't generate assembly language code: it just impact how future code will be). Only declarations, that the compiler needs (at compile time) to know how to

Comment: understand the code. So even if you have twice a declaration `void somefunc(int); void somefunc(int);` or even two identical `typedef`, it should be ok. And anyway, if it is not, `glib.h` authors did prevent double parsing. You are not supposed to know which `.h` includes which `.h` that in turn includes which `.h`...

Comment: But of course, if authors of `glib` did, as you did, include some actual code (like your `foo` and `bar` function), then, surely, it would be bad to include it twice. But they didn't. Nobody does that.